# dot graph generation too slow around 5000 nodes and 7000 edges

Tags: dot

I convert a graphviz dot file to pdf which has 5000 nodes and 7000 edges.
Two hours passed, it's not finished yet.
is there a fastway to do it?

Comment: Which OS, which version of `dot`, which output format? Do you think a graph with 5000 nodes and 7000 edges will still be readable / useful? Which program generated the dot file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer.

- add **-v** to the command line to help understand where dot is getting stuck (**dot -v -Txxx ...**)
- try using one of the other layout engines (fdp, neato, circo, ...)
- The Dot User Guide says: *For completeness, we note that dot also provides access to various parameters which play technical roles in the layout algorithms. These include mclimit, nslimit, nslimit1, remincross and searchsize.*
- This web search leads to more help: *mclimit OR maxiter dot*